# Sending form with Select List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using this code to post value of selected item from the view to the controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyVar, (SelectList)ViewData["List"])
        <button name="Button" value="Valider">Valider</button>

}
```

Is there a way to send the value when the selection change in the select list (without the need to click on the button) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do it via [**JQUERY**](http://jquery.com/), on dropdown selection change post the form via jquery:

add id to drop down:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyVar, (SelectList)ViewData["List"], new { id="SomeId"})
```

and write jquery event:

```
$(function(){

    $("#SomeId").change(function(){

        $(this).closest("form").submit(); // this will post the form
    });   

});
```

Comment: you could also directly insert the javascript/jquery code to the html-attributes: new {id="SomeId", onchange="$(this).closest(\"form\").submit()"}

Answer (score 2):

If you name the SelectList in the ViewData the same as the name of the variable in your Model, MVC will figure the rest out for itself.

So your dropdown would look like:

```
@Html.DropDownList(ViewData.MyVar, String.Empty)
```

This is as opposed to naming your ViewData item 'List'.