# How to bind value from database to Dropdown List in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is My Model

```
public class InsertOrder
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }     
}

public List<InsertOrder> getcustomerid()
{
    List<InsertOrder> customerlist = new List<InsertOrder>();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataReader Datareader;
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerID,FirstName FROM customers", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            Datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Datareader.Read())
            {
                InsertOrder ID = new InsertOrder();
                ID.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(Datareader["CustomerID"]);
                ID.CustomerName = Datareader["FirstName"].ToString();

                customerlist.Add(ID);
            }
            Datareader.Close();
            return customerlist;
        }
    }
}
```

How to give in the view page

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25361876/3846058) might be of some use to you.

Comment: Whats the model that contains the property you want to bind the selected `InsertOrder` to?

Comment: To bind value to a Dropdownlist @StephenMuecke

Comment: @jabi, Your not understanding. You need a model with a property to bind the selected `InsertOrder` to. In Moksh's answer below, it assumes you have a model with a property `int SampleDropDownValue` so the `CustomerID` value of the selected `InsertOrder` is bound to the value of `SampleDropDownValue`

Answer (score 0):

```
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var customerList = new InsertOrder().getcustomerid();

                ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(customerList, "CustomerId",CustomerName") ;
                return View(YourModel);
            }
```

At View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SampleDropDownValue, Model.CustomerList , "--Select--")
```

Comment: You can avoid the for loop: 

`ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(customerList, "CustomerId", "CustomerName")`